# Relative Path after generating Executable JAR (issue with JasperReports)

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, relative-path

I was developping an application of some kind of stock management that provides to the users the possibility of generating tickets and reports they need with a PDF format.

Im done with the developpement and everything works fine on NETBEANS, But when I tried to Build my Executable Jar file, I figured out that everything works fine except the part of tickets/reports generation, And I'm sure it's coming from the Path that I've specified in the source code, Here is a piece of Code :

```
  try
{
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("currentime",currentTime);
    jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File("./src/BeanASDatasource.jrxml"));
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"journal.pdf");
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
 }
```

PS : The file "BeanASDatasource.jrxml" is located under the default package.

Comment: I get no bugs when I click " Generate ticket",nothing happens simply, like the path specified hasn't been found.

Comment: I think you could add checking of your jasperDesign object on null after this code: `jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File("./src/BeanASDatasource.jrxml"));`

Comment: The problem is clear, when I run the JAR version the programm can no more locate BeanASDatasource.jrxml, I tried with the absolute path And it worked ( But its gonna work only on my computer )....